# Footer year dynamically change Wix Velo

Tags: javascript, velo

I would like to have the year in the footer automatically change each year without manually doing it and have the text all together.For example [(c) 2022 MyWebsite All rights Reserved] Is there a way with Wix Velo? This is what I have but I must be missing something.

Text field id = #footerYear

$w.onReady(function () {

let year = new Date();

$w('#footerYear')

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, format your question with code blocks

Answer (score 1):

Go to masterpage.js file. You can edit footer and header code only there.

```
$w.onReady(function () {
    let now = new Date();
    $w('#footerCopyrightText').text = `(C) ${now.getFullYear()} MyWebsite All rights Reserved`;
});
```

https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/text/text

Answer (score 0):

well I don't really use Wix Velo but I quickly get to getting started examples and there it is, you can select with `$w('#footerYear')` and to change it's value change the `text` prop on it for elems. Please do check getting started from [Wix Velo](https://learn-code.wix.com/en/article/1-hello-world#step-1-designing-the-page)

```js
// in your onReady function
let date = new Date();
$w('#footerYear').text = date.getFullYear();
```